# converting dataframe to csv keeping the datatypes of columns intact

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this :

```
  user        embs
abc100      [-0.12, 0.3, 0.96]
abc101      [-0.82, 0.93, 0.906]
abc102      [-0.092, 0.73, 0.71]
...
```

I have converted it to csv using `to_csv` but when I read the csv file it displays like this:

```
 user        embs
abc100      [-0.12 0.3 0.96]
abc101      [-0.82 0.93 0.906]
abc102      [-0.092 0.73 0.71]
```

As a result, I am unable to apply an element wise multiplication function which takes elements  of any two numpy array (the `embs` column) and multiply them after reading the file .

The function is:

```
def Embedder(emb_1, emb_2):
        return (emb_1* emb_2)
```

Can anyone help me in ways to save the dataframe to a csv in the same format as that of the dataframe?

Comment: How are you reading the CSV? If you use pandas `read_csv`, it should already be numpy arrays.

Comment: I am reading it using ```read_csv```.

Comment: That's strange, I think. If you are reading it using pandas, it should be pandas series which behaves very similar to numpy arrays. But at any rate, you are always just convert them back to numpy arrays after you read it right? Not sure if there is a way to do this while writing into the file. I think it's a matter of reading it in the format that you are interested in.

Comment: `to_csv` writes the `str` display of each array element, which `read_csv` loads as strings.  Putting arrays in dataframe elements adds a '3rd' dimension to your data that the 2d `csv` format cannot handle cleanly.  If  the elements were lists instead, it would be easier to convert them back (one by one).

Comment: @hpaulj Can I convert the ```emb``` column of the dataframe from numpy.array to a list using ```tolist()``` >